# Telegram bot. Работа с историей сообщений

Tags: telegram-bot

Каким образом можно получить предыдущее сообщение от пользователя?

Comment: Что значит "предыдущую строку"? Предыдущее сообщение?

Comment: Да, именно, предыдущее сообщение. Для управления многоуровневым меню.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [ForseReply](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#forcereply) и поле `reply_to_message` объекта [Message](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#message) для организации многоуровневого меню.
**Пример** (для **C#**)**:**

```
public static ReplyMarkup ForceReply { get; } = new ForceReply
   {
       Force = true,
       Selective = true
   };   

public static async Task AskUser(TelegramBotClient bot, Update update)
   {
       await bot.SendChatActionAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.Typing);
       await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Type your answer", true, false, update.Message.MessageId, Keyboards.ForceReply);
   }  

 //...    

if (update.Message.ReplyToMessage != null && update.Message.ReplyToMessage.Text.Contains("Type your answer"))
   {
       //do something with user data from update.Message.Text
       // ...
       await bot.SendChatActionAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, ChatAction.Typing);
       await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, $"{update.Message.From.FirstName}, ok.");
       return;
   }
```

Так же можно попробовать предложенный в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582796/183842) вариант.