# Как посмотреть кто и что писал в чат боту телеграм? getUpdates выдает только - {"ok":true,"result":[]}

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, бот

Почему метод:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXX/getUpdates
```

выдает только:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[]}
```

?

Сообщения боту отправлялись и он на них реагировал.

Как получить выдачу типа:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"update_id":8393,"message":{"message_id":3,"from":{"id":7474,"first_name":"AAA"},"chat":{"id":,"title":""},"date":25497,"new_chat_participant":{"id":71,"first_name":"NAME","username":"YOUR_BOT_NAME"}}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Данный метод возвращает только новые сообщения. Если бот уже реагировал на некие отправляемые ему сообщения, то он их уже получил (скорее всего этим же методом) и они помечены сервером Telegram как полученные. Соответственно, при каждом новом запросе они возвращаться уже не будут, иначе вы бы каждый раз получали всю историю сообщений с момента создания бота. В данном случае, у вас есть два варианта:

- Вести лог получаемых ботом сообщений и пользоваться им на своё усмотрение.
- Поиграться с параметром `offset` метода `getUpdates`. Подробнее здесь: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates

Например: `https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXX/getUpdates?offset=-10`

Comment: есть конкретный пример получения объекта **Update** по его **id**? методом **getUpdates**, передавая **update_id** в качестве значения параметра **offset** сделать это не получается