# входящие сообщения для бота telegram

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

пытаюсь собрать бота на php. базовую логику, кажись, понял, но осталась проблема... как с помощью метода getUpdates получить не все сообщения боту, а только, скажем так, актуальные... и по какому критерию можно определить эту актуальность? скажем, хотя б последнее письмо от каждого пользователя, на которое бот еще не ответил

Comment: документацию читали?

Comment: @Anatol да, но с параметрами offset и limit так толклм и не рпзобрался

Comment: а что значит актуальные? Последние?

Comment: Вообще плохо понятна задача

Comment: @Anatol к примеру, пользователь написал команду /start и метод getUpdates вернул json с данными о сообщении от пользователя, скрипт данные распарсил, увидел команду /start и дал соответствующий ответ. при втором вызове getUpdates информация о /start для бота уже неактуальна, так как он на неё ответил. актуально второе сообщение пользователя, чтоб ответить только на него. вот у меня и встал вопрос, как вызывать getUpdates, чтоб получать только нуждающиеся в ответе сообщения, а не все

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582796/183842 тут посмотрите

Comment: @Anatol спасибо большое! попробую вечером разобраться

Comment: если удалось решить задачу - добавьте описание решения в виде ответа и отметьте его как правильный, возможно кому-то он поможет

Comment: если не удалось - дополняйте вопрос деталями

Answer (score 5, accepted):

разобрался. у данного метода есть параметр offset. если задать его значение, update_id + 1, то данный метод будет возвращать только те сообщения, которые были получены после последнего вызова. то есть, все те, которые пришли боту после последнего вызова getupdates

пример вызова:

```
api.telegram.org/bot<token>/getupdates?offset=<update_id + 1>
```

Comment: А я заморочился и сделал webhook. Теперь telegram сам отправляет мне события, а я моментально на них реагирую. Работает быстро и хорошо. Единственный недостаток - нужно доменное имя, точка наружу и SSL. Но все равно рекомендую.

Comment: @ilyaplot согласен, это гораздо удобнее. просто у меня нет пока конкретной цели или конкретной идеи для бота. экспериментирую)