# Как ждать сообщение от пользователя telegram bot php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Использую библиотеку https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk.

**Требуется** :  Что-то на подобии такого примера

*bot* : Напишите мне ваше имя
*User* : Oleg
*bot* : Как ваши дела, Oleg?

Нужно как-то после вопроса бота ждать ответа от пользователя.Как можно извлечь ответ?
Видел похожую тему [Как посмотреть кто и что писал в чат боту телеграм? getUpdates выдает только - {"ok":true,"result":[]}](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582786/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC-getupdates-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE/582796#582796) но, не совсем понял как это можно сделать через offset.

Comment: про offset: насколько я знаю, отрицательные значения этого параметра просто очищают очередь обновлений

Comment: @mymedia Ну это я и сам понял. А как с его помощью можно реализовать то о чём я спрашивал выше?

Comment: Всё так же не разобрался с проблемой. Разве никто не сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: [возможный дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/683506/183842)

Comment: @Anatol а тот, в свою очередь, — возможный дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746598/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-telegram-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python

Comment: @NickVolynkin нет, скорее наоборот. Между вопросами 5 месяцев

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Требования:
- скрипт должен хранить состояние беседы (например, в БД) и идентифицировать это состояние по ID пользователя (назовем это сессией).
- у бота должна быть ([веб-хука на получение сообщений](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#setwebhook))

Сначала бот отправляет сообщение с запросом имени пользователю

Пользователь отвечает, телеграм в ответ на сообщение шлёт запрос на скрипт (адрес обработчика нужно настраивать в веб-хуке на получение сообщения). Скрипт получает данные, вносит в  сессию ответ пользователя и посылает запрос в телеграм (шлет новое сообщение пользователю)

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы получать ответы от пользователя и знать на какой вопрос ответил пользователь, нужно сделать следующее:

1. В БД сохранить так называемые бот flow. Например:

   1. Как зовут?
   2. Сколько лет, ну и так далее
2. Когда бот отправил вопрос пользователю записать `ID` этого вопроса и `chatId`  в базу.
3. Когда пользователь ответит на вопрос в базе посмотреть какой вопрос задал бот и вуаля.

Текст сообщения пользователя будет в обьекте `message.text`

Библиотека которую вы используете не совсем подходит к вашей задаче. Она ориентирована на команды боту.

Вот неплохое описание-руководство, которое надеюсь вам поможет https://habr.com/post/347482/